# Intellij IDEA returns different results with vs. without enabled REPL for Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, debugging, intellij-idea, jackson, read-eval-print-loop

I create a Kotlin scratch file in Intellij IDEA and use my current project's module classpath in order to access all libraries of the project (i'm using Jackson in this example)

In both scenarios I have declared the following class:

```
class Test(var first: String = "a", var second: String = "b")
```

Without REPL enabled

```
val jsonAsString = "{\"first\": \"a\", \"second\":\"b\"}"

println(ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonAsString, Test::class.java).first) // prints out "a"
```

"a" is printed out as expected

With REPL enabled the ObjectMapper.readValue() throws the following exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `Line_2$Test` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"first": "a", "second":"b"}"; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1904)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1349)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1415)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:351)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:184)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3597)
```

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the bug and created an issue - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-21598/Scratch-REPL:-%22InvalidDefinitionException:-Cannot-construct-inst. Feel free to follow it.